# Can't find specified item in keychain

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I am attempting to follow this tutorial https://pilloxa.gitlab.io/posts/safer-passwords-in-gradle/. But even though I have set up the keys in the key chain, whenever I run this command

```
security find-generic-password -s android_keystore -w
```

I get the following message

```
security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

I can't seem to use that command to find any of the keys that exist in the keychain. And when I try to fully build the apk I get an error that the key doesn't exist. I managed to build the apk when I use a plaintext password though, I just can't seem to get the keychain one to work

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you've added the password into a Keychain under the *Default Keychains/login*

After that try to enter the same command.

P.S. If everything's working, except the build still has the same error(the password is incorrect), try to change:

```
def pass = getPassword("YOUR_USER_NAME","android_keystore")

def pass = getPassword("android_keystore","android_keystore")
```

**YOUR_USER_NAME** - it's the name, which you declared in the keychain for the android_keystore